# $cacheFactory deletes my cache when page reloads

Tags: angularjs, caching, cachefactory

So I have a simple factory that creates cache object

```
.factory('jsonCache',function($cacheFactory){
    console.log("Creating cache");
    return $cacheFactory('weatherCache');
});
```

I'm then calling that cache object inside my controller like so by passing it in like so. But for some reason the data is not persistent. Every time I reload the page, the cache is empty again.

Any ideas? Did I miss something?

```
.controller('citiesListCtrl',function($scope,$http,$filter,jsonCache){

    jsonCache.get('weatherCache');
    console.log(jsonCache); <----- EMPTY

    $http.get(url)
        .then(function(response) {

          jsonCache.put('weatherCache', response.data.records);
          console.log(jsonCache); <--- HAS DATA
    });
)}
```

Answer (score 3):

The data is not persistent for very good reason: `$cacheFactory` cache is nothing but a thin wrapper around plain JS object.

You can check [the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.5/src/ng/cacheFactory.js) to make sure that the service does nothing but simple LRU algorithm.

For data persistence use persistent storage (probably [angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) or [angular-localForage](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage)). `angular-cache` is an another replacement for built-in `$cacheFactory` [that supports persistence](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache#using-angular-cache-with-localstorage).

Comment: So what is the purpose of if it is not persistent? For instance I want to cache JSON data. What would the use case be for it other wise?

Comment: @Showcaselfloyd To cache parsed JSON and reuse it across the app. Think of it as of in-memory cache.

Comment: So I think I'm very confused. I was under the impression that's what I was trying to do. For instance it's easy to cache data like this on the server in PHP because you can save it to the server's tmp dir. In this case if the data just gets destroyed every time you refresh the page it's hard for me to understand why you would need it.

Comment: @Showcaselfloyd `$cacheFactory` is used internally for caching templates, after app bootstrapping they are requested only once and then borrowed from cache, this is the use case. There are very few good use cases for persistent client-side cache, on the other hand, especially in SPA. And it should be controlled by hand. How would you manage it if it would greedily cache everything and never clean up after itself?